# SIGABRT in raise.c?

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I am currently developing a small C++ program that can manage a [TShock](https://tshock.co/xf/index.php) server remotely using the server's REST API.

Recently, I had to reinstall Debian on the computer I'm using to develop the program, and now I get a SIGABRT error at runtime:

```
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
In __kernel_vsyscall () ()
56  ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
#1  0xb731f307 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
```

In case you are wondering, I mirrored my previous installation.

If it helps, here is a list of what I use to develop the program:

- Debian stretch/sid, i386 architecture

  - Code::Blocks version svn 10561
  - GCC toolchain (installed versions are GCC 4.8, GCC 4.9, and GCC 5)
  - GDB 7.10

I also use the following libraries:

- wxWidgets 2.8.12
- Boost 1.59.0 (I built it according to [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#easy-build-and-install))
- cpp-netlib 0.11.2 (I built it using `CMake`)
- SuperEasyJSON

Small precision: I'm starting to suspect wxWidgets, because I'm starting to get a similar error in the wxWidgets examples my teacher gave me.

Thanks in advance for your answer(s).

Also, if you need more info, don't hesitate to ask.

EDIT: I found the reason behind this problem. wxWidgets 2.8 and my program were built with different versions of GCC. I invoked GDB from the terminal, and I got this:

```
Fatal Error: Mismatch between the program and library build versions detected.
The library used 2.8 (no debug,Unicode,**compiler with C++ ABI 1002**,wx containers,compatible with 2.6),
and your program used 2.8 (no debug,Unicode,**compiler with C++ ABI 1009**,wx containers,compatible with 2.6).
```

Since it is a different problem, this question can be closed.

Comment: Very hard, nearly impossible to give you a diagnosis what actually happened.

Comment: Recompile your code.

Comment: The problem was the ABI version mismatch. I just added -fabi-version=2 to the compiler options.

Comment: Hm that shouldn't have happened with a proper distribution. Have you manually compiled the library? If so, recompile. If not, install the needed version of the library too.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: I installed wxWidgets 2.8 using `apt-get`. It seems that the wx2.8 packages available on the `sid`/`unstable` branch of Debian are built with GCC 4.x, and Code::Blocks defaults to GCC 5.2.